# How to create multiple windows simultaneously in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I'm creating a game using Libgdx and i write a debugger for that. Now i want to display debugging information in another `LwjglApplication`.

Is there any way to open multiple windows in Libgdx desktop application ?

Answer (score -1):

1. Create two classes extending `Game` or implementing `ApplicationListener`, one for main game and one for debug window.
2. In `DesktopLauncher` class, create two `LwjglApplication`s with objects of aforementioned classes.

   ```
   public static void main (String[] arg) {
       LwjglApplicationConfiguration mainConfig = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
       new LwjglApplication(new MainGame(), mainConfig);

       LwjglApplicationConfiguration debugConfig =new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
       new LwjglApplication(new DebugGame(), debugConfig);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one OpenAL context may be instantiated at any one time.`

Comment: @SaeedMasoumi that can be fixed using `LwjglApplicationConfiguration.disableAudio = true;` however, this will not be the last of the issues presented by doing this.